# Bad operand types for binary operator '=='

Tags: java, class, netbeans

i have this code compiled in jdk 1.6, it works in one computer but shows error in another one

```
public static void rellenarLinea(final StringBuffer psLinea, final ResultSet rs, final int plNumberOfColumns, final JDateEdu poDateEdu, final ResultSetMetaData rsmd) throws java.sql.SQLException {
        rellenarLinea(psLinea, rs, plNumberOfColumns, poDateEdu, rsmd, false);
    }
    /**
     * rellena psLinea, en funciona de la fila actual del ResultSet
     * @param psLinea buffer de la libea
     * @param rs resulset posicionado
     * @param plNumberOfColumns numero de columnas
     * @param poDateEdu Objeto dateEdu instanciado(da igual el valor)
     * @throws SQLException excepcion
     */
    public static void rellenarLinea(final StringBuffer psLinea, final ResultSet rs, final int plNumberOfColumns, final JDateEdu poDateEdu, final ResultSetMetaData rsmd, boolean pbSiempreBorrarEspaciosFinal) throws java.sql.SQLException {
        Object loValor;
        Class loClase;
        int lTipo = -1;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        //se crea la linea
        psLinea.setLength(0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= plNumberOfColumns; i++) {
            loValor = rs.getObject(i);
            lTipo = rsmd.getColumnType(i);
            //comprobamos si es nulo
            if (loValor != null){
                //para formatear correctamente la fecha
                loClase = loValor.getClass();
                if((loClase == java.sql.Date.class) ||
                   (loClase == java.util.Date.class) ||
                   (loClase == java.sql.Time.class) ||
                   (loClase == java.sql.Timestamp.class)){
                    //anadimos ano,mes,dia
                    if ((loClase == java.sql.Date.class) ||
                        (loClase == java.util.Date.class) ||
                        (loClase == java.sql.Timestamp.class)){
                        c.setTime((java.util.Date)loValor);
                        poDateEdu.setDate(c);
                    }
                    //anadimos hora,minuto,segundo
                    if(loClase == java.sql.Time.class){
                        c.setTime((java.sql.Time)loValor);
                    }
                    if(loClase == java.sql.Timestamp.class){
                        c.setTime((java.sql.Timestamp)loValor);
                    }
                    poDateEdu.setHora(c.get(c.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                    poDateEdu.setMinuto(c.get(c.MINUTE));
                    poDateEdu.setSegundo(c.get(c.SECOND));
                    psLinea.append(poDateEdu.toString());
                }else if (loClase == Boolean.class){
                    if(((Boolean)loValor).booleanValue()){
                        psLinea.append(JListDatos.mcsTrue);
                    }else{
                        psLinea.append(JListDatos.mcsFalse);
                    }                    
                }else if (loClase == (Double.class)){
                    psLinea.append(JFormat.msFormatearDouble((Double)loValor, JFormat.mcsDOUBLENOCIENTIFICO).replace(',', '.'));
                } else if (loClase == (byte[].class)){//para los binarios
                    String lsResult=new String((byte[])loValor);
                    if(lsResult.indexOf(JFilaDatosDefecto.mccTransparentacionCambioLinea10)>=0 ||
                       lsResult.indexOf(JFilaDatosDefecto.mccTransparentacionCambioLinea13)>=0 ||
                       lsResult.indexOf(JFilaDatosDefecto.mccSeparacion1)>=0      ){
                        throw new SQLException("Uso de caracteres no validos en el campo " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                    }
                    psLinea.append(lsResult);
                }else {
//                    if(lTipo==java.sql.Types.CHAR || lTipo==java.sql.Types.NCHAR){//los char siempre tienen muchos espacios al final q los anade la BD
                    if(lTipo==1 || lTipo==-15 || pbSiempreBorrarEspaciosFinal){//los char siempre tienen muchos espacios al final q los anade la BD
                        psLinea.append(rTrim(loValor.toString()));
                    }else{
                        psLinea.append(loValor.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            psLinea.append(JFilaDatosDefecto.mccSeparacion1);
        }
    }
```

Compiler shows Bad operand types for binary operator '==' in "else if (loClase == (byte[].class))" line

Any help would be appreciate, thank you in advance

PS. Im using JDK 1.6 for compiling this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

going through your code-lines:

```
           }else if (loClase == (Double.class)){
                psLinea.append(JFormat.msFormatearDouble((Double)loValor, JFormat.mcsDOUBLENOCIENTIFICO).replace(',', '.'));
            } else if (loClase == (byte[].class)){//para los binarios
```

you use: loClase == (Double.class)  which wont compile for me (even with JDK 1.6).

you could try the following:

```
           }else if (loClase instanceof Double){
                psLinea.append(JFormat.msFormatearDouble((Double)loValor, JFormat.mcsDOUBLENOCIENTIFICO).replace(',', '.'));
            } else if (loClase instanceof byte[])){//para los binarios
```

Comment: Im using SOurce/Binary Format: 1.4 and Java Platform JDK 1.6, i get the error only in "else if (loClase == (byte[].class))" line, it shows as hint "lambda expression not expected here, bad operand types for '==' first Class second <none> "

Comment: weird.. i thought lambda expressions came with JDK 1.8. - maybe the reason is another jdk version on your other computer?

Comment: I have just figured out that if i remove "()" it works, like this way: 

}else if (loClase == byte.class)

Now i really dont understand


Btw both computers have JDK 7 and JKD 6 only